# How to show all the data in the row SQL

Tags: sql

I want to know the query that could show me the data  in a row in Inner Join table

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e504.jpg)

as you see from the pic that I have 4 tables in the inner join table , I want to know how to show the blue 1 in BeefId with WorWOId 1 in on table

I can show all data in table beef by using

```
select a.* from Tbl_Beef a 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Add b ON  a.Id = b.Id ;
```

but I don't know how to join WorWOId with it

Comment: This has nothing to do with `C#` tag

Comment: sorry i don't know why i add it i'm just working on it with SQL now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just make another join between `Tbl_Add` and `Tbl_WithOrWithot`

```
SELECT a.* 
   FROM Tbl_Beef a 
 INNER JOIN Tbl_Add b 
   ON  a.Id = b.Id 
 INNER JOIN Tbl_WithOrWithot w 
   ON b.WorWOID = w.id
```

Comment: it shows me data from the beef table with id number 1,2 and 3

Comment: I edited the answer because i had an error..i hope you saw the updated one. If it helped you please accept it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are wanting tbl_withorwithot also? sorry if misunderstanding the question.

```
Select * From Tbl_Add a 
INNER JOIN Tbl_Beef b ON a.BeefID = b.Id 
INNER JOIN Tbl_WithORWithot c ON a.WorWOID = c.Id
```

This will only show records that exist in all 3 tables, so you can reorder and change to outer joins if you need different.

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks actually it gave me a clue ^^ . 
ill see what ill do thanks again.